# $_SESSION['ip'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] security issue

Tags: php, session

So I was just told (by one of my users) that my login wasn't secure and that a session could be pretty easily hijacked.

Can anybody tell me why and how I can correct this?

This is my user class:

```
  class User
  {
    private $_db;
    private $_isLogged;

    public function __construct()
    {
      if (!session_id())
      {
        session_start();
      }
      $this->_db = Db::init();
      $this->_checkLogin();
    }

    public function isLogged() 
      {
          return $this->_isLogged;
      }

      public function login($username, $password)
      {
      $sth = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
      $sth->execute(array($username));
      $result = $sth->fetch();

      if ($result)
      {
        if ($result['password'] == md5($password))
        {
          $this->_setLogin($result);
          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    public function logout() 
    {
      session_destroy();
      setcookie ("simpleLogin", "", time() - 3600, '/');
    }

    public function fbLogin($fbId)
    {
      $sth = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook = ?");
      $sth->execute(array($fbId));
      $result = $sth->fetch();

      if ($result)
      {
        $this->_setLogin($result);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    private function _setLogin($userData)
    {
      $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
      $_SESSION['id'] = $userData['id'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $userData['username'];
      $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

      try {

        $sth = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE users SET ip = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $sth->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $userData['id']));

        $forCookie = array(
          'id' => $userData['id'],
          'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
          'username' => $_SESSION['username']
        );

        setcookie('simpleLogin', serialize($forCookie), time()+60*60*24*30, '/');

      } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Database error: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }

      private function _checkLogin()
      {
      $this->_isLogged = false;

      if (isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'])
          {
        $sth = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['id']);
        $result = $sth->fetch();

        if ($result['ip'] == $_SESSION['ip'])
        {
          $this->_isLogged = true;
        }
      }
      else if (isset($_COOKIE['simpleLogin']) && $_COOKIE['simpleLogin'])
      {
        $cookieData = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['simpleLogin']));

        $sth = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $cookieData['id']);
        $result = $sth->fetch();

        if ($result['ip'] == $cookieData['ip'])
        {
          $this->_isLogged = true;
          $this->_setLogin($result);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sessions are server-side only, as they're run through PHP. They are secure. Cookies on the other hand.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection via the *simpleLogin* cookie.

Comment: It looks like you're setting the user login data into a cookie.  Why would you do that?  Assigning these values to the $_SESSION superglobal should suffice and remove the security issues introduced by assigning this information to a cookie.

Comment: Your class is full of bad practices, including Global state, Computations in constructor, OCP and SRP violations...

Comment: @NickCoons How can I keep a user logged in without having the data in the cookie?

Comment: @DaveJust Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @metareviewr I can, but it's gonna take me a week. Instead google for "SOLID principles", "Google Clean Code Talks" and read this: http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html

Comment: **Don't** use **MD5** anymore! Switch to bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: @metareviewr That's the purpose of using sessions.  When you start the session, it creates a session ID which it stores as a cookie.  Each time the browser makes a request to the server, this session ID is passed with that request.  The information that you store in $_SESSION is stored on the server side, so it's not accessible from the client.  The session can still be hijacked by intercepting the session ID (which is why sensitive connections should go over https), but it's more difficult than finding the clear-text cookies stored in the browser.

Comment: @NickCoons so simply removing the ip from the cookie will fix that without causing any issues?

Comment: @metareviewr You'll have to also make sure that all the references you made to the cookie will be made to the $_SESSION variable instead. Also be sure that you're using session_start() before referencing $_SESSION, otherwise it won't contain any value.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the SQL injection hole by changing this:

```
$sth = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $cookieData['id']);
```

...to this:

```
$sth = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :ident");
$sth->execute([':ident' => $cookieData['id']]);
```

This assumes that `DB::init()` returns a `PDO` instance.  If it's an instance of a custom class, you'll need to implement parameter binding in that class.